# insert datalist of input range from array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, html-select

In my project I have chosen to modify some elements of an array with the select. Any changes that are made will have consequences in the matrix.

```html
<li class="list-group-item">    
    <tr *ngFor="let row of matrix; index as r">
        <td *ngFor="let columns of row; index as c">
            <tr *ngIf="r === 2">
                <td *ngIf="c === 0">   
                     <select [(ngModel)]="object[r][c]" (change)="onSelectChange(r,c)">
                        <option [ngValue]="a.num" *ngFor="let a of arrayComparation">
                            {{a.char}}
                        </option>          
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </td>
    </tr> 
</li>
```

```
arrayComparation = [
    { id: 1, char: "1/9", num: 1 / 9 },
    { id: 2, char: "1/8", num: 1 / 8 },
    { id: 3, char: "1/7", num: 1 / 7 },
    { id: 4, char: "1/6", num: 1 / 6 },
    { id: 5, char: "1/5", num: 1 / 5 },
    { id: 6, char: "1/4", num: 1 / 4 },
    { id: 7, char: "1/3", num: 1 / 3 },
    { id: 8, char: "1/2", num: 1 / 2 },
    { id: 9, char: "2", num: 2 },
    { id: 10, char: "3", num: 3 },
    { id: 11, char: "4", num: 4 },
    { id: 12, char: "5", num: 5 },
    { id: 13, char: "6", num: 6 },
    { id: 14, char: "7", num: 7 },
    { id: 15, char: "8", num: 8 },
    { id: 16, char: "9", num: 9 }
  ]
```

Instead I would like to choose these values via the input range. How do I make the range read the array values? I tried to enter the range like this but it doesn't read me the floats.

```html
<input type="range" class="form-range" min="0" max="9" step="any" id="customRange" list="arrayComparation" [(ngModel)]="object[r][c]" (change)="onSelectChange(r,c)">
                                    <datalist id="arrayComparation">
                                        <option value="1/9"></option>  
                                        <option value="1/8"></option>  
                                        <option value="2"></option>
                                        <option value="3"></option>
                                    </datalist>
```